# Get device current free/used/app memory like Xcode debugger

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, ram

I have found some answers regarding this topic but most of them only cover the current app memory usage, i need to get this info in whatever format is available (UInt64, String, etc..), also being looking at [this Pod](https://github.com/Shmoopi/iOS-System-Services) but it is on Objective-C and in this particular case i need it in Swift 4, thanks.

Comment: You can use Objective-C code via Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64665) this is not a good practice since it behaves different from different devices architectures to another ones, and also it might change in any moment leading to weird information being shown to the users facing this data.
Also none of the code found matched Xcodes own measurement.